Computing Jacobian determinants of matrix-valued function
Assume we want to integrate a function $ F:R^{n \times n}\to R$ over some set $ A \subset R^{n \times n}$, that requires us to perform a transformation, i.e., we want to do something like
$$\int_A F(M) \, \Bbb dM =\int_{\phi^{-1}(A)} F(\phi(M)) \vert \det (\phi'(M))\vert \, \Bbb dM,$$
where $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism of $R^{n \times n}$. Typically, one would identify $R^{n \times n} \simeq R^{n^2}$ via vectorization to calculate the Jacobian matrix $\phi'(M)$. Is there a more convenient formalism that allows us to compute the Jacobian determinant without vectorization by directly working in the matrix space?
